# Auto select the first match in react auto complete

Tags: reactjs, debugging, autocomplete, highlight, onselect

I am using https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-autocomplete

where i have the same issue as raised in

```
https://github.com/reactjs/react-autocomplete/issues/239
```

and also after bit of reading i came to know there is a option to do so

```
https://github.com/reactjs/react-autocomplete/issues/266
```

please let know **how  to select the first item in the list by default**, so that the user can hit enter and it will select the first in the list

My current implementation is as shown below

```
<Autocomplete
                    ref={el => this.input = el}
                    value={this.state.value}
                    inputProps={inputProps}
                    wrapperStyle={{ position: 'absolute', display: 'inline-block' }}
                    items={this.state.srnList}
                    getItemValue={item => item.name}
                    shouldItemRender={matchSRN}
                    onChange={(event, value) =>
                        this.setState({ value })
                    }
                    onSelect={(value) => this.onSelectSRN({ value })}
                    renderItem={(item, isHighlighted) =>
                        <div className= "menu" style={{ background: isHighlighted ? '#e1e1e1' : 'white' }} key={item.name}>
                            {item.name}
                        </div>
                    }
                />
```